# update_option_$option action not working as expected

Tags: settings-api, options

I have a custom admin page that uses the settings API. Form submits to options.php. After submission I am attempting to do something in the background. I am hooking into `update_option_$option` to do this. This works fine, except on first run. No matter what I've tried, I simply can't get the `update_option_$option` hook to run. Is this intended behavior?

```
function my_register_settings() {
     register_setting('my_settings_group', 'my_custom_option');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_register_settings');

function do_after_update($old, $new) {
     // Do the stuff here
}
add_action('update_option_my_custom_option','do_after_update', 10, 2);
```

the `do_after_update()` will only fire the second time and beyond. I found a work around by adding `add_option('my_custom_option');` into my registration function, but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `update_option_{$option}` will only fire on **updated** options, ie, not brand-new ones.

Reading the code for [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/), I see this:

```
/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/option.php */
if ( apply_filters( "default_option_{$option}", false, $option, false ) === $old_value ) {
    // Default setting for new options is 'yes'.
    if ( null === $autoload ) {
        $autoload = 'yes';
    }

    return add_option( $option, $value, '', $autoload );
}
```

... before the `update_option_{$option}` hook. Since your `$old_value` is unset, it's `false`, and so, since `false` === `false`, you're hitting the `return add_option()` code.

[`add_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) has its own, related action hook: [`add_option_{$option}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_option_option/). So you should be able to hook into that, too.

Your updated code:

```
function my_register_settings() {
     register_setting('my_settings_group', 'my_custom_option');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_register_settings');

function do_after_update($old, $new) {
     // Do the stuff here
}
add_action('update_option_my_custom_option','do_after_update', 10, 2);

function do_after_add( $new ) {
    // Do the stuff here
}
add_action( 'add_option_my_custom_option', 'do_after_add' );
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and indeed update_option_{$option} will not fire on "new options" . Using the add_option_{$option} along with update_option_{$option} solved my problem. Good answer!

Comment: update_option doesn't seem to work when you have multiple options stored as one array value.

Comment: @RickHellewell Haven't checked yet, but why wouldn't it? Hooking into the array and not into the specific item contained in the array should work.